# How's it possible that we can invoke resources and get methods inside routes.rb without error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Lets say I have a rails routes.rb file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   resources :articles
end
```

I guess Rails has made the necessary inclusions(via "require" or "include") so that whenever routes.rb is invoked by itself or from another ruby file(either in the rails console environment or from the rails server which we can run via the "rails server" command), it functions well and in a error-free way. These inclusions made it possible that we can call the

```
Rails.application.routes.draw
```

method inside the routes.rb file.(So Rails has made Rails.application.routes available for routes.rb.)
But how is it possible that we can call the `resources` method inside routes.rb? If `resources` is a class method of some class A or a method of some module B (which as I noted, is possible for Rails to make available to routes.rb), then the only way `resources` could have been invoked inside routes.rb - would be, to use

```
A.resources
```

or,

```
B::resources
```

(correspondingly), right?

This also applies to other methods we use inside routes.rb, such as

```
get
```

Comment: Ruby + DSL: https://www.leighhalliday.com/creating-ruby-dsl

Look for instance_eval